# replacing value of a model property at serialization in web api

Tags: json, model-view-controller, serialization, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

In my web api, I want some Model's password value to be replaced with some other value. e.g. if password is 'abcdef', I just want to replace it with '**********'. So that at web end, I get response value with '**********' instead of actual value. How can I define some attribute for that purpose and how serialization process can be modified?

Any help will be appreciated. thanks !!!

Comment: do you mean encapsulation ? [Wiki-Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

Comment: yes. but only for specific properties. I want to define a custom attribute which can be applied on any property of a model, like [Required]

Comment: I suggest you this article. [MVC Password Model](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_security.asp)

Comment: thank you. but I am not looking for this. I want to change serialization process for replacing values